# how to add child array with dynamic key in loop PHP

Tags: php

i have string like this

```
$string = 'root.1.child1.2.nextnode.3.anothernode.4.var';
```

exploded by "." and created array like this

```
$arr = array('root','1','child1','2','nextnode','3','anothernode','3','var');
```

how i can convert this array to something like this ?

it should be dynamically convert because in some cases nodes in string are in a number different with the sample .

```
  ["root"]=>
  array(1) {
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["child1"]=>
      array(1) {
        [2]=>
        array(1) {
          ["nextnode"]=>
          array(1) {
            [3]=>
            array(1) {
              ["anothernode"]=>
              array(1) {
                [3]=>
                array(1) {
                  [var]=>
                  NULL
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example using recursive function.

```php
$array = ['root', '1', 'child1', '2', 'nextnode', '3', 'anothernode', '3', 'var'];

function getNestedArray(array $arr, int $idx = 0) {
    if ($idx + 1 <= count($arr)) {
        return [$arr[$idx] => getNestedArray($arr, $idx + 1)];
    }

    return null;
}

$output = getNestedArray($array);

var_dump($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be quit easily achieved by referencing the output and looping over the exploded array:

```php
$output = [];
$reference = &$output;
foreach ($arr as $el) {
    if (is_numeric($el)) {
        $el = (int)$el;
    }
    $reference = [];
    $reference[$el] = null;
    $reference = &$reference[$el];
}
```

This also checks whether the element is a number and casts it to an integer if it is. The `$output` variable will contain the final array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive function

to do though

```php
$flatArray = array('root','1','child1','2','nextnode','3','anothernode','3','var'); // your array

function createNestedArray($flatArray)
{
    if( sizeof($flatArray) == 1 ) {
        return [ $flatArray[0] => null ];  // for the case that paramter has one member we need to return [ somename => null ]
    }
    
    $nestedArray[ $flatArray[0] ] = createNestedArray(array_slice($flatArray, 1)); // otherwise we need to call createNestedArray with rest of array 
    
    return $nestedArray;
}

$nestedArray = createNestedArray($flatArray); // the result
```